# Android: display image during async background streaming task

Tags: android, stream, android-asynctask

I am trying to retrieve JPGs from an MJPG Stream using an async task. I first thought, i could let the task continuously be running and just letting the buffered JPGs pop up in the onProgressUpdate() method. But this doesn't seem to work, because the method only displays integers, no drawables...what I tried:

```
private class StreamTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        image = readMJPGStream();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        imView.setImageDrawable(image); // << doesn't work
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas? What approach should I try?

Thank you very much in advance!

Huck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now got it running this way:

```
public class StreamActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{

// ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    imView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imView);

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (connected){
        image = readMJPGStream();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        imView.setImageDrawable(image);
    }
};

public Drawable readMJPGStream() {
    //...
return image;
}
}
```

The only problem is that my `while` loop is not fast enough. Any ideas are very much appreciated!

Huck

Comment: try

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public run() {
        imView.setImageDrawable(image);
      }
    }

In your run method.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a AsyncTask, the `doInBackground` is called, but it is only run once.  I'm not sure what `readMJPGStream` does, but assuming it blocks until an image is retrieved, its certainly possible that onProgressUpdate gets called several times while your image is still null, then once image get set to something valid and doInbackground quickly exits, there are no further calls to `OnProgressUpdate`.

You should probably put the call to `imView.setImageDrawable` in `onPostExecute` to make sure it gets called when the image has been downloaded.  You may also need to call `invalidate()` on your image view to ensure it gets redrawn.  Additionally, if you intend to loop and continue downloading images, you'll need to devise a mechanism of triggering updates.  In reality, the issue you're having is because you want 'on demand' get on the UI Thread, but you're dependent on calls to `onProgressUpdate`.  You'd have much better luck using a Handler and your own Runnable/Thread because then when an image download completes, you can post to the UI thread (using the `Handler`) without having to wait for the `onProgressUpdate`.

Comment: Tanks Nick, yes I thought, there was a way tu use `doInBackground` in a continuous fashion. If I use it only once `imView.setImageDrawable` draws nicely in `onPostExecute`. I will now give Runnable/Thread another shot. `invalidate()` was a good hint too!